# Storing secret data inside session

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I have backend app in which I am using passport.js like this:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'login',
    passwordField: 'passwd'
  },function(username, password, done){
         // call to external api to check if login & passwd are correct
         var user = { user: username, passwd: password };
         return done(null,user);
}));

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null,user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  done(null,id);
});
```

The problem is that I use `username` and `password` fields for `basicAuth` to communicate with main REST API. So I have to keep both fields (`username` and `password`) inside session (u can see this in my localstrategy callback) to use them for basicAuth for external server. How I can make it safe? I guess that storing it inside session is not a good idea because session is saved in cookie right? How I can store session data on server and just session/user id on server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Session data is stored server-side, so it is actually safe to store the username and password in the session as long as you aren't letting the client access it. A session is not stored in a cookie, but instead, the cookie is what tells the server which session is associated with the client.